# Laravel Excel Maatwebsite loop through optional columns per row

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have my Excel export working 90%. The first lot of columns are straight forward and taken from my collection. The last two fields come from a related model, I'm interested in the Test Name and Test Score. 
For each row (athlete), there is multiple tests. I need each test that the athlete did to be a column.

I got it working, but the Test Scores are not aligning correctly. If athlete 1 did Test A, B and C, but athlete 2 only did Test B and C, it puts athlete 2's B score under the A test column. See picture attached. The yellow highlight from 147.000 should all shift to the right, so must the last two rows, the 3.6 and 3.8 are scores for the 20m sprint test.
Please help with the score alignment.

[image]

Controller:

```
    if(count($tests)){
        $insert_results = array();
        foreach($tests as $key => $t) {            
            $insert_results[$key]['institution'] = $t->section->institution->name;
            $insert_results[$key]['sport'] = $t->section->sport->name;
            $insert_results[$key]['sportlevel'] = $t->section->sportlevel->long_name;
            $insert_results[$key]['testdate'] = $t->test_date->format('Y-m-d');
            $insert_results[$key]['name'] = $t->athlete->name;
            $insert_results[$key]['surname'] = $t->athlete->surname;
            $insert_results[$key]['ethnicity'] = $t->athlete->race;
            $insert_results[$key]['gender'] = $t->athlete->gender;
            $insert_results[$key]['age'] = $t->age;
            $insert_results[$key]['weight'] = $t->weight;
            $insert_results[$key]['height'] = $t->height;
            foreach($t->results as $r){
                $insert_results[$key]['test'.$r->battery->name] = $r->score;
            }
        }
        $filename = $section_obj->institution->name . '_' . $section_obj->sport->name . '_' . $section_obj->sportlevel->name . '_' . $date;
        $sheetname = $section_obj->sport->name . '_' . $section_obj->sportlevel->name;

        Excel::create($filename, function($excel) use($insert_results, $sheetname) {

            $excel->sheet($sheetname, function($sheet) use($insert_results) {
                $sheet->fromArray($insert_results);
                                // Auto filter for entire sheet
                $sheet->setAutoFilter();
                // Freeze first row
                $sheet->freezeFirstRow();

            });

        })->export('xlsx');
    }else{
        return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'No results found for test day '. $date]);
    }
```